# python: how can I double left click to get a point in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a map ,and now I want to double left click to zoom-in the map and left click to get a point.How should I do? I know 'ginput' command but it seems can't work with double-left-click.

```
latsize=[39,45]
lonsize=[-72.,-66]
plt.figure(figsize=(7,6))
m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=min(latsize)-0.01,urcrnrlat=max(latsize)+0.01,\
            llcrnrlon=min(lonsize)-0.01,urcrnrlon=max(lonsize)+0.01,resolution='h')#,fix_aspect=False)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(int(min(latsize)),int(max(latsize))+1,1),labels=[1,0,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(int(min(lonsize)),int(max(lonsize))+1,1),labels=[0,0,0,1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: You double click with a mouse, not with Python. So there is a lot of context missing here. Try to explain what you are doing. You have a map? What map? A paper map? A mapping? A google map? What?

Comment: I use basemap to get a Geography map.

Comment: What library defines `Basemap`? Is it a common python library or your own custom code?

Comment: So you want your code to *handle* the event that is sent when you double-left-click on your map, that you have drawn using matplotlib? How do you display the map?

Comment: @BryanOakley http://matplotlib.org/basemap/  -- mapping toolkit built ontop of matplotlib

Comment: basemap is a common python library. After I double click the map,I want to plot a new map with " basemap " around the point which I click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using matplotlib? You have to register an event handler for mouse events. All the information you need can be found here:

- [Event handling and picking](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html)

Look at handling `button_press_event` or `button_release_event`. If you follow the link for the MouseEvent class, you'll see it has a boolean double click indicator `dblclick`.

- [MouseEvent](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.MouseEvent)

Here is a bare-bones example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def handle_mouse_press( event ):
    if event.dblclick:
        print "Can haz dblclikz???"

fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', handle_mouse_press)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm studying the information you offer!thank you very much